# ASP.Net MVC C# Assign Roles off checkbox and list of users

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I have a list of my Admins in a dropbox and a list of my Users in a panel with their name and a checkbox for their name. I have a button in my panel so I can assign the users to an admin. I am wondering how I would set this up in my controller assigning a role to a user isn’t hard but doing It this way im not 100% sure about. Here is what I have.

//my view

```
        <div class="row">
            @for(var i = 0; i < Model.lstUsers.Count(); i++)
            {
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(u => Model.lstUsers[i].SelectedUsers)
                        <label>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(u => Model.lstUsers[i].Name)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(u => Model.lstUsers[i].UserId)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(u => Model.lstUsers[i].Name)
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-0 col-md-12">
                    <input type="submit" value="Assign Role" class="btn btn-success" />
                    @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Dashboard", "SuperAdmin",
                     null, new { @class = "btn btn-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>      //Model                                                     public class AdminModel
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class UserModel
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool SelectedUsers { get; set; }
    public string AssignToAdmin { get; set; }
}
public class AssignRolesModel
{
    public List<AdminModel> lstAdmins { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Choose Admin")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public List<UserModel> lstUsers { get; set; }
    public int? AssignToAdmin { get; set; }
    public int? CreatedBy { get; set; }
}   // Controller   have a [httppost] and bring my assignrolesmodel object into the controller
```

Get the list of users which I have but I need to check the users checkboxes and assign them to admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i currently came up with. Its not 100% finished yet but I can get a user and assign the user to an admin it for sure works with 1 user i have to test more than one.
I'd be interested in any input or comments to what I am doing.
Thank you

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult AssignAdmin(AssignRolesModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            if(model.lstUsers == null)
            {
                TempData["Error"] = "There are no Users to Assign Roles";
                model.lstUsers = UserList();
                model.lstAdmins = AdminList();
                return View(model);
            }

            var selectedUsersCount = (from user in model.lstUsers
                                      where user.SelectedUsers == true
                                      select user).Count();
            if(selectedUsersCount == 0)
            {
                TempData["Error"] = "You have not Selected any User to Assign Roles";
                model.lstAdmins = AdminList();
                model.lstUsers = UserList();
                return View(model);
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                List<UserModel> users = new List<UserModel>();
                ApplicationUser au;
                var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
                var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store);

                model.CreatedBy = 1;

                foreach(var u in model.lstUsers)
                {
                    if(u.SelectedUsers == true)
                    {
                        users.Add(u);
                    }
                }

                foreach(var u in users)
                {
                    au = context.Users.Where(x => x.Id.Equals(u.UserId,
                        StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();
                    manager.AddToRole(au.Id, "Admin");
                }

                TempData["Success"] = "Roles Assigned Successfully";
                return RedirectToAction("AssignAdmin");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }           

        return View();
    }
```